# In Python, how do I remove subdirectories that do NOT contain a certain file extension (ie .pdf)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subdirectory, os.walk

I'm trying to write a program that physically removes all subdirectories of a directory that do not have any `.pdf` files in them.

I think the solution requires `os.walk` but haven't figured out much.

I made a recursive function to do this but I'm not sure if it works

```
def isDirectory(path):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        for file in listdir(path):
            newpath=os.path.join(path,file)
            isDirectory(newpath)
        if listdir(path)== []:
            os.rmdir(path)
            return
        else:
            return
    elif os.path.basename(path)=='.pdf':
        #array.append(os.path.basename(path))
        return
    else:
        os.remove(path)
        return
```

Comment: Iterate through the contents of any subdirectories returned from `os.listdir()`, if a pdf file is found while doing this, add the subdirectory to a deletion list and go on to the next subdirectory. If no pdf files are found in the subdirectory, just go on to the next one. After doing this for all the subdirectories, go through and delete all of them that were added to the deletion list. Postponing deletion will make it easier to test because you can check the results before doing anything difficult to undo.

Comment: Do you intend to search and possibly delete sub-subdirectories as well, or only immediate subdirectories?  On a related note, is the goal to nuke every directory that lacks a PDF file, or to save all the PDF files?  For instance, if you have exactly _one_ file under the current directory:  `./upper/lower/file.pdf`, do you delete `upper` (since it contains no PDF files of its own), or do you preserve it (since nuking `upper` would require deleting `lower` and the PDF file `lower` contains)?

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase I intend to delete sub-subdirectories as well that do not contain pdf's as well and in that case you mentioned I would not delete upper.  Ive make a recursive function to this but I'm not sure if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a function performing what required.
I've added several `print` statements to show its working and document it.

```
def removeNonPDFDirectories(dpath):
    '''Visit 'dpath', removing any subdirectory not containing any PDF
       file. Return True if 'dpath' is removed.
    '''
    import os
    if os.path.isdir(dpath):
        print 'Entering', dpath
        entries = [os.path.join(dpath, entry) for entry in os.listdir(dpath)]
        subdirs = filter(os.path.isdir, entries)
        print '    Subdirectories:', subdirs
        if all(map(removeNonPDFDirectories, subdirs)):
            print '    All subdirectories were removed.'
            files = filter(os.path.isfile, entries)
            pdf_files = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.pdf')]
            print '    PDF files:', pdf_files
            if not pdf_files:
                try:
                    for f in files:
                        os.unlink(f)
                        print '    Removed file', f
                    os.rmdir(dpath)
                    print '    Removed directory', dpath
                except OSError as e:
                    # An error occurred: assume directory is not empty.
                    print '    ERROR:', e
                    print '    Keeping directory', dpath
                    return False
                # Directory was removed: report to caller.
                return True
        # Directory must be kept: report to caller.
        print '    Keeping directory', dpath
        return False
    else:
        return False
```